# TreeView in tkinter freez while updating

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ping, ttk

I am trying to update a treeview every second from a database with clients and ping time status,
if the successful ping was before some:X time the row will be red(or odd red to distinguish).

`update_tree` always is running with and sleeping 1 sec between each loop.
Also instead of deleting all the children i insert to each obj `iid` the values and tags

Here is update_tree function:

```py
def update_tree(self, tree):
    index = {'id': 0, 'addr': 1, 'ping': 2}
    self.iid_count = 0
    while True:
        count = 0
        clients = DB().get_curs().execute("SELECT ID,ADDR,PING FROM CLIENTS").fetchall()
        childrens = tree.get_children('')

        # update whole treeview if bool table or bool ping true or no childrens 
        if childrens == ():
            for client in clients:
                tree.insert('', END, iid=client[index['id']], text='', values=(
                    "CON", client[index['ping']], client[index['addr']], client[index['id']], self.iid_count),
                            tags=('blue',))
                self.iid_count += 1
            self.db_row_count = DB().get_curs().execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLIENTS").fetchone()
        else:
            for client in clients:
                client_ping_time = self.pinger.str_to_time(client[index['ping']])
                # even rows
                if count % 2 == 0:
                    # if the time in db for ping + 5 sec is bigger than now meaning it was created in past 3 secs
                    if (client_ping_time + timedelta(seconds=3) > datetime.now()):
                        tree.item(client[index['id']], values=(
                            "CON", client[index['ping']], client[index['addr']], client[index['id']], count),
                                    tags=('seccsess_even',))
                    # if last seccsessful ping was before 5 sec
                    else:
                        tree.item(client[index['id']], values=(
                            "CON", client[index['ping']], client[index['addr']], client[index['id']], count),
                                    tags=('fail_even',))
                # odd rows
                else:
                    if (client_ping_time + timedelta(seconds=3) > datetime.now()):
                        tree.item(client[index['id']], values=(
                            "CON", client[index['ping']], client[index['addr']], client[index['id']], count),
                                    tags=('seccsess_odd',))
                    else:
                        tree.item(client[index['id']], values=(
                            "CON", client[index['ping']], client[index['addr']], client[index['id']], count),
                                    tags=('fail_odd',))
                count += 1
            self.db_row_count = DB().get_curs().execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLIENTS").fetchone()

        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: `tree.after` can pass values without lambda. try using `tree.after(1000, self.update_tree, tree)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem:

After having some more experience with ui's (in Qt though)
I can clearly see that there are two main reasons why the window freezes for each update.

1. (And this is probably the big one) You should never call `time.sleep` while running an event loop (tkinter have an event loop just like any other ui framework) if you do so, ***the application just wont handle events therefore will freeze***
2. calling a db might also block the event loop for noticeable time (especially if its on the network or a big query) although in this case it was probably very short since i was running a local sqlite server and very small queries.

### The solution:

As suggested by @[derek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15518276/derek) I need to drop the while loop in the function ans call it with `after` to add this to the event loop like so:

```py
iid_count = 0
index = {'id': 0, 'addr': 1, 'ping': 2}
def update_tree(self, tree):
    count = 0
    ping_update_bool = self.pinger.ping_clients_db()
    clients = DB().get_curs().execute("SELECT ID,ADDR,PING FROM CLIENTS").fetchall()
    childrens = tree.get_children('')

    # update whole treeview if bool table or bool ping true or no childrens
    if childrens == ():
        for client in clients:
            tree.insert('', END, iid=client[self.index['id']], text='', values=(
                "CON", client[self.index['ping']], client[self.index['addr']], client[self.index['id']], self.iid_count),
                        tags=('blue',))
            self.iid_count += 1
        self.db_row_count = DB().get_curs().execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLIENTS").fetchone()
    else:
        for client in clients:
            client_ping_time = self.pinger.str_to_time(client[self.index['ping']])
            # even rows
            if count % 2 == 0:
                # if the time in db for ping + 5 sec is bigger than now meaning it was created in past 3 secs
                if (client_ping_time + timedelta(seconds=3) > datetime.now()):
                    tree.item(client[self.index['id']], values=(
                        "CON", client[self.index['ping']], client[self.index['addr']], client[self.index['id']], count),
                                tags=('seccsess_even',))
                # if last seccsessful ping was before 5 sec
                else:
                    tree.item(client[self.index['id']], values=(
                        "CON", client[self.index['ping']], client[self.index['addr']], client[self.index['id']], count),
                                tags=('fail_even',))
            # odd rows
            else:
                if (client_ping_time + timedelta(seconds=3) > datetime.now()):
                    tree.item(client[self.index['id']], values=(
                        "CON", client[self.index['ping']], client[self.index['addr']], client[self.index['id']], count),
                                tags=('seccsess_odd',))
                else:
                    tree.item(client[self.index['id']], values=(
                        "CON", client[self.index['ping']], client[self.index['addr']], client[self.index['id']], count),
                                tags=('fail_odd',))
            count += 1
        self.db_row_count = DB().get_curs().execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLIENTS").fetchone()

    tree.after(1000, self.update_tree, tree)
```